# How to use javascript to open the modal when connecting the API so that the user can see the animation effect?

Tags: javascript

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
let photo = document.querySelector('.photo');
let svg = document.querySelector('svg');

let data = [{
  title: "dog",
  age: 10,
  rank: [{
      rankStatus: 'behind'
    },
    {
      rankStatus: 'generally',
      rankNum: '20'
    },
    {
      rankStatus: 'excellent'
    }
  ]
}]

let rankStatusArr = data[0].rank.map(item => item.rankStatus);
let rankNum = data[0].rank.find(item => item.rankNum).rankNum;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  svg.style.display = "block"

  axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
    .then((response) => {
      // 设置处理程序以在加载图像后显示图像
      photo.addEventListener('load', () => {
        svg.style.display = "none"
        modal.style.display = "flex";
      });
      // 添加“加载”处理程序后设置图像源
      photo.src = response.data.message;
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

  // 排名狀態在 popup 打開後再載入動畫
  let progress = rankNum;
  let dot = document.getElementById("dot");
  var dotPosition = (progress / 30) * 100;
  dot.style.left = dotPosition + "%";

  let txt = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');
  for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    txt[i].innerHTML = rankStatusArr[i];
  }
})

wrap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})

modal.addEventListener('click', function() {
  modal.style.display = "none"
})
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap .photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrap #progress-bar-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.wrap #progress-bar-container .progress-bar {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.wrap #progress-bar-container .progress-bar .txt {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#progress-bar-1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progress-bar-2 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#progress-bar-3 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-out;
}

svg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

svg .load {
  stroke-dasharray: 0 500;
  animation: rot 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rot {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 500 500;
  }
}

.green {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.3.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn'>open</button>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="wrap">
    <img class="photo" src="" alt="photo">
    <div id="progress-bar-container">
      <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar-1">
        <p class="txt">1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar-2">
        <p class="txt">2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar-3">
        <p class="txt">3</p>
      </div>
      <div id="dot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- load -->
<svg width="240px" height="240px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="90" stroke-width="10" stroke="gainsboro" fill="none"></circle>
  <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="90" stroke-width="10" stroke="darkturquoise" fill="none" class="load"></circle>
</svg>
```

I encountered a little difficulty in the following requirements. The first difficulty is that I hope that the popup will not be opened until the picture is fully loaded! But I hope that when the popup is opened, the dot can add animation and run to the specified progress position, but it seems that the animation I want to appear has already run before it is opened, and the user will not see the moving animation effect. The second problem is that I want to add a green color to the rankStatus font on the screen if the rankNum is included in the rankStatus object, but I am a novice in programming and don't know which section to add to achieve this. Hope to get your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first difficulty, you can add an event listener to the photo element which will be triggered when the image is loaded. Inside this event listener, you can set the display of the modal to 'flex' and the display of the svg element to 'none'.

To solve the second difficulty, you can use an if statement inside your rankStatusArr loop. This statement should check if the rankNum is included in the rankStatus object and if so, add a class to the txt element which adds the green color style.

```
let txt = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');
for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
  txt[i].innerHTML = rankStatusArr[i];
  if (rankNum === rankStatusArr[i]) {
    txt[i].classList.add('green');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that my programming foundation is not very good. I added txt[i].classList.add('green'); according to the suggestion I heard, but it doesn't seem to make the text turn green? What should you do about the first point you mentioned? i still don't understand

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/KKBYPEW?editors=1111